# Should we allow the tags *left* and *right*?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There is already the use of the tags [left](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left) and [right](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/right) and I wanted to ask whether anybody else sees a problem with using them.

Personally I think because there is no clear definition of "left" and "right" (see [What is meant by the “left” and the “right”?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-is-meant-by-the-left-and-the-right)) we should not be using the tags. This could lead to a lot of discussion whether an issue or a question is adequately tagged.

I would move to ban those two tags.

Answer (score 5):

I say nuke em!

I *am* a horribly biased libertarian in that respect, but they *are* however a fairly useless binary classification in many cases.

And you don't want people fighting over which one belongs with certain topics (cough National Socialism) either, if such things happen to come up.

(Edit: Oops, didn't notice they were both already on [a question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/319/was-hitlers-regime-a-right-wing-regime) about that.)

Answer (score 5):

Based on the answers here, I've merged and synonymized both with [ideology](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ideology). This'll both prevent them from coming back into use, and (hopefully) represent the true intentions of those using them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we should move to (and possibly synonymise to) a tag to which they collectively belong... I can't think of the exact word at the moment but something like [leaning](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leaning) though I know there's a better word for it...

Comment: That occurred to me too ... I don't think `leaning` is discoverable enough, though (perhaps a question on ux.se is in order). Maybe `wing`, with `right` and `left` as synonyms?

Answer (score 0):

I'll steal an idea from @Graham, and propose "[political-orientation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-orientation)" instead.

And burninate any questions that don't use Nolan Matrix instead of left-rite axis (j/k :))))

Answer (score -2):

The main problem I can see with banning [left](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left) and [right](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/right) is that some useful questions are likely to come up regarding their use and meaning, beyond the one linked to in the question. Neither tag has seen a *lot* of use so far, and I think both questions that have employed it:

- [(Why) does the US left promote federal powers over state powers?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/338/97)
- [Was Hitler's regime a right-wing regime?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/319/97)

... are good ones.

For the time being, I'd be in favour of leaving the tags alone (and maybe revisiting the issue if we do have problems down the line).